# swift errorhandling: scope

Tags: error-handling, scope, swift2

How large should the scope be for error handling in swift 2? 
I understand error handling (I think), but I am also doubting on the implementation details. If I have a function that calls throwing functions, how should I handle the scope of my do-try-catch?

Should I do this:

```
func doLotsOfErrorProneWork()
{
  //everything in scope
 do {
    try f1()
    f2()
    f3()
    try f4()
    f5()
 } catch {}
}
```

or this:

```
func doLotsOfErrorProneWork()
{
  //smallest scope possible
  do {
    try f1()
  } catch {}

    f2()
    f3()

  do {
    try f4()
  } catch {}

  f5()
}
```

Does it make a difference? What is the difference?
One difference is probably the difference in error that is thrown between f1 and f4.
But suppose there is only one throwing function.

```
func doLotsOfErrorProneWork()
{
  //everything in scope
  do {
    try f1()
    f2()
  } catch {}

}
```

or this

```
func doLotsOfErrorProneWork()
{
  //smallest scope possible
  do {
    try f1()
  } catch {}
    f2()
}
```

Or is it just a matter of style?

Comment: it is just a matter of style and what you want to do in case some function throws an error (how to recover from that situation). there is also a lot of scenarios not mentioned in your question

Comment: @user3441734 it is **NOT** a matter of style. Your first sentence contradicts itself - "style" or "what to do", one is a stylistic decision, the other is an application logic decision.

Comment: @luk2302 sorry for my bad english. when i wrote about style, i thought about  functional vs. procedural paradigm and not about coding style. to find the proper word (paradigm) , i have to use dictionary. you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule:

When an error occurs everything after that particular `try` statement is skipped and the next catch block in the same scope is executed.

The question of using one or multiple `do - catch` blocks depends on the scenario whether there is still code to be executed in case of an error.

- In the first example `f2()`- `f5()` are never reached if `f1()` fails.
- In the second example all functions are executed.

Comment: Ok. what about all the functions leading up to a throwing function. Do you include them in the scope? In the example, suppose only f5 throws.

Comment: The `do` block can be used as a normal local scope but it should only contain the code which is directly affected by the `try` statement(s). Usually the first `try` follows the `do`, all `good` code follows the `try` and the `bad` code follows the `catch`.